# Не срабатывает триггер Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Такой триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER server_master_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE "SC_Tag".server_partition_function();
```

Как понимаю, для `copy` он не годится?
вид copy

```
COPY "T_HardWareTag" ("ID_HardWareTag", "F_ServerName", "F_OPCServerName", "F_IDOPCTag", "F_TagReadTime", "F_DateStart", "F_TagName_ID", "F_RealHardWare_ID") FROM stdin;
16  ASUTPMOF    OPC.EnLite-exe.1    Device5/ReactPerSum 30000   2014-08-20 10:52:15 16  \N
17  ASUTPMOF    OPC.EnLite-exe.1    Device5/ReactSum    30000   2014-08-20 10:52:21 17  \N
19  ASUTPMOF    OPC.EnLite-exe.1    Device6/ActiveSum   30000   2014-08-20 10:52:30 19  \N
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вопрос в том, будет ли срабатывать такой триггер в результате команды `COPY` - да, должен срабатывать

```
CREATE TABLE test(id int);

create or replace function test_before_insert_on_copy() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'done';
    return NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER test_before_insert_on_copy_trg BEFORE INSERT on test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_before_insert_on_copy();

test=# COPY test (id) FROM stdin;
Вводите данные для копирования, разделяя строки переводом строки.
Закончите ввод строкой '\.'.
>> 1
>> \.
NOTICE:  done
КОНТЕКСТ:  COPY test, line 1: "1"

test=# select version();
version                                                                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.6 on amd64-portbld-freebsd10.1, compiled by FreeBSD clang version 3.4.1 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot1-final 208032) 20140512, 64-bit
(1 строка)

test=#
```

Comment: в практике нет((( он же рассчитан на BEFORE INSERT

Comment: И что? У вас же все равно идет вставка строки. Какая у вас версия postgresql?

Comment: 9.3 версия у меня

Comment: Привел выше пример для 9.3

Comment: а вы понимаете что копи в дампе немного иначе выглядят?

Comment: Это взято из дампа. Поясните - что именно выглядит иначе?

Comment: посмотрите вопрос

Comment: Единственное, что я вижу - в вашем дампе нет окончания команды в виде \.

Comment: он длинный. но да в конце слэш есть.

Comment: В таком случае - все должно работать как часы :)